# Area element for hyperbolic coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, area, hyperbolic-geometry, parametrization, jacobian

Wikipedia has a nice writeup on hyperbolic coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_coordinates

In particular, they introduce the parametrization
\begin{equation}
x = ve^u \\
y = ve^{-u}.
\end{equation}
I would like to find the area element, $dA$, in this coordinate system. We have the Jacobian:
\begin{pmatrix}
ve^u & e^u \\
-ve^{-u} & e^{-u}
\end{pmatrix}
which has determinant $2v$. Therefore, $dA = 2|v|dudv$. Is this correct? This is quite an interesting result if so. Much simpler than I expected, and very similar to the polar area element $rdrd\theta$.

edit: $v$ $\rightarrow$ $|v|$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $dA=2|v|\,du\,dv$? Note that $v$ can be negative, and for the coordinate transformation we need the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant. We don't have this 'problem' in polar coordinates because $r$ is non-negative.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen Right. That was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct. Hyperbolic “rectangles” get bigger and bigger as you move away from the origin, same effect than moving away from the pole in polar coordinates.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks!